# Pullbacks of LCS-valued distributions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, schwartz-distributions, locally-convex-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a locally convex space. Since the distributions $\mathcal{D}'\!(M)$ ($M$ a manifold) are a nuclear space, there is a canonical meaning to the topological tensor product $X\,\widehat{\otimes}\,\mathcal{D}'\!(M)$. Is there some way to define the pullbacks for such distributions (along an inclusion $N\subset M$ of a smooth submanifold)? For ordinary distributions, this is precisely when the wavefront set is disjoint from the conormal bundle of $N$. When $X$ is finite dimensional, there exists besides the wavefront set also the polarization set which gives more refined information on the singularities, but I have not found a comparable characterization of the existence of pullbacks, nor do I know what to do in the infinite-dimensional case (see e.g. [this paper by Sahlmann and Verch](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0008029.pdf), p. 3, for references on the polarization and wavefront sets of vector-valued distributions in the finite-dimensional case).

I believe this question to be very well motivated by QFT since we often want to integrate conserved currents over submanifolds to obtain conserved charges. However, these currents are actually unbounded-operator-valued distributions, so integrating them over submanifolds makes no sense a priori and one needs some sort of pullback. I have seen at least one workaround for this in the literature (in [this excellent book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-009-0491-0)), but it did not appeal directly to this kind of microlocal analysis, which strikes me as the most natural approach. (See also [my other question on Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452829/integrating-distributions-over-submanifolds).)